# python plistlib file invaded by cocoa values?

Tags: python, plist

I'm using plistlib to create and update a simple plist file in OS X.  A tester in Norway is getting an error from plistlib:

```
File "../axeomatic2/normal/build/pyi.darwin/aomDSP/out03-PYZ.pyz/plistlib", line 406, in parse
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 8
```

Looking at the plist file that was generated on his system, I see fields like this interspersed with the expected entries:

```
NSTableView Sort Ordering       Array
...
NSTableView Hidden Columns      Array
...
NSTableView Columns             Array
...
NSNavLastRootDirectory          Array
```

If I give him a plist from my system it works fine, but any time the program decides it needs to create one from scratch it gets an error.

I thought perhaps it was an encoding problem, but we're both on OS X 10.7 and both using the OS X version of UTF-8.

Any ideas as to what might be happening, or how I might troubleshoot this remotely?

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem before, after I try [biplist](https://github.com/wooster/biplist), it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Binary plist support has been added to `plistlib` since python 3.4.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/plistlib.html

Answer (score 0):

There's actually two categories of `plist` format. One is actually simple XML file (which `plistlib` knows how to parse with `expat`), the other one is `binary property list`.

Unfortunately they both share the same suffix `.plist`, and all the tools from Apple treat them transparently (e.g. you don't know if you are working with an XML plist or a binary plist, using tools like `defaults`)

Like @northtree said, the `biplist` package is the right tool to read/write the binary plist file.

UPDATE:

You can also use `plutil(1)` that comes with OSX to convert any `plist` file back to XML format, and then processed by `plistlib`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html